# Implement a DidSet for all UIViewController's title in app

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am trying to set automatically a parameter of each ViewController's of my app depending on the title I set for them.

Is it possible to build a generic DidSet on the title property of UIViewController ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably is, but it's not necessary, you could just wrap both functionalities in a function or a variable of your own:

```
extension ViewController {
    func setTitle(_ title: String) {
        self.title = title
        // Do whatever you need to do else
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add property observers to properties of existing types in extensions. To add a property observer, you'd need to modify the source code of the actual type, which of course isn't possible in case of `UIViewController`.

However, there are a couple of other alternatives.

You can create a `UIViewController` subclass, where you override the `title` property and add a `didSet` on this override property. You just need to make sure all your view controllers will subclass your base class, not `UIViewController`.

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {
    override var title: String? {
        didSet {
            print("title was set to \(title ?? "nil")")
        }
    }
}

BaseViewController().title = "title"
```

You can also extend `UIViewController` with a new method, where you set the `title` property and add any other functionality here that you'd add to the `didSet`. With this solution, you can keep subclassing `UIViewController`, you won't need a `BaseViewController`, but you'll need to make sure you call `setTitle` instead of directly assigning a value to the `title` property.

```
extension UIViewController {
    func setTitle(_ title: String?) {
        self.title = title
        print("title was set to \(title ?? "nil")")
    }
}

UIViewController().setTitle("other")
```